# How to use -webkit-fill-available on Edge and IE11?

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm trying to use `-webkit-fill-available` cross browsers. I have the following code:

```
min-width: -webkit-fill-available;
min-width: -moz-available;
min-width: stretch;
```

It works well on Chrome, Firefox, but not on Edge and IE11. On Chrome and Firefox the element width fills its parent element, on Edge and IE11 the attribute is not recognised.

How can I make IE11 have the same effect as `-webkit-fill-available`?

**EDIT**: here is an example, the `select` width does not fill its parent div on Edge and IE:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.control {
  min-width: -webkit-fill-available;
  min-width: -moz-available;
  min-width: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <select class='control' name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: IE does not support that property....and never will

Comment: @Paulie_D so is there a work around on IE?

Comment: Nope....IE11 is a dying browser. Edge is the way forward. Perhaps you could show us the problem in a [mcve] so we can offer practical alternatives.

Comment: @Paulie_D I added an example.

Comment: Yes, but what is the **problem**?

Comment: @Paulie_D If you check the question code in Edge or IE you'll see the `select` does not occupy its parent div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, you can try to set the min-width: 100% for the control class.

The min-width: 100% declared at the start will be used by browsers which ignore both the -moz and -webkit-prefixed declarations or do not support -moz-available or -webkit-fill-available.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.control {
     min-width: 100%;
     min-width: -moz-available;          
     min-width: -webkit-fill-available;  
     min-width: fill-available;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
  <select class='control' name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in the MS Edge legacy browser:

[image]

Output in the IE 11 browser:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think `min-width: 100%` is the right thing to do.